# How to get the id of the selected item in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

Here is the code and i can't figured out why it doesn't work, or what i have to change to make it work...

this is not updated:

```
<strong data-bind="text: SelectedId" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZP79w/732/

I want to have an object which has the value of id of the selected value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not related to your KO computed code, but your HTML.

`strong` is not a [self closing element](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html). So the browsers interpret your second `strong` as the part of the first one and the KO `text` binding replaces it.

You just need to properly close both your `strong` tags:

```
<strong data-bind="text: choice().id"></strong>
<strong data-bind="text: SelectedId" ></strong>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0wwL4xqw/).